# Compose filename inside expect script

Tags: files, scripting, expect, tcl

I have a file which several lines, let's say:

**server_file.txt:**

```
[main]
server1 param1 param2 param3
server2 param1 param2 param3
```

I want to take the first value of last column to compose a filename within an `expect` script so that the filename is: *server2_030417T124700*, where *030417T124700* is the current date when the file was created.

I have been able to achieve the date part with these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_file ./log/post.log
<some_code>
system mv ./log/post.log ./log/post_[clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}].log
```

But where I have "*post_*" I would like to have "*server2*" based on last line of server_file.txt

I have tried to do it by using a variable that executes the bash command `tail -1 server_file.txt | awk '{print $1}'` with no success and I think it is possible to do it without using a bash command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these 3 lines of `tcl` code in your `expect` script to get the server name.

```
set fp [open "server_file.txt" r]
while {[gets $fp data] >= 0} {set servername [lindex [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $data] 0]}
close $fp
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been done avoiding the `tail` command and using the proper syntax for `awk` when executed from `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_file ./log/post.log
set servername [exec awk {FNR>1 {print $1}} server_file.txt]
system mv ./log/post.log ./log/"$servername"_[clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}].log
```